# SQL LIKE Operator for multiple combinations of string spacing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return all results where a column contains two variables (@Width and @Height, in that order).

This is how I have it set up:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.description LIKE '% '+@Width+'"% '+@Height+'"%';
```

This works great for records that are correctly spaced like this: `HIP 6" X 4" Sign Digital`. However, there are many records that are not spaced correctly, such as this: `HIP 6"X4" Sign Digital`, or `HIP 6" X4" Standard Sign`, etc..

I have tried removing the required spaces from the LIKE, which takes care of that issue, but then I get incorrect records like `HIP 16" X 24" Sign Digital`. I only want to search for the exact number, not any number that ends with the matching digits.

How can I account for different combinations of spacing while still only searching for two exactly matching variables? Is there any way to do so without having to go in and standardize thousands of records that were entered before I started working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Width varchar(10)='6', @Height varchar(10)='4';

select *
from 
(
values 
('HIP 6" X 4" Sign Digital'), ('HIP 6"X4"'), ('HIP 6" X4"'), ('6" X4" Digital'), 
('HIP7 6" X 4"'), ('HIP 6"     X        4" Sign Digital'), ('HIP 6"X       4" Sign Digital'),
('HIP 16" X 4"'), ('HIP 6" X 24"'), ('HIP6 " X 4"')
) as t(description)
where '.' + replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(description,  ' ', '- '), ' -', ''), '- ', ' '), 'X ', 'X'), ' X', 'X') like '%[^0-9]'+@Width+'"X'+@Height+'"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the spaces?

```
where replace(table.description, ' ', '') like '%' + @Width + '"%' + @Height + '"%'
```

You probably want to search for:

```
where replace(table.description, ' ', '') like '%' + @Width + '"x' + @Height + '"%'
```

Comment: This still incorrectly returns records like 16" X 24" when 6 and 4 are entered. I only want it to return 6" X 4".

Comment: Replace leading `%` with ` [a-z]`